# window.onbeforeunload fires in IE for partial postback events

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, back-button, onbeforeunload

I want to warn users when the refresh or press back button of the browser if they have entered some thing in text boxes. So I have used window.onbeforeunload function to do it.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (if user hasn't entered any thing) {
        return;
    }
    return 'Entered data will be lost.';
};
```

this javascript code works fine in Firefox and chrome. But in IE this function fires for buttons with partial post backs. 
Any solution to overcome this problem in IE ?
Thanks :)

- It's happen because of Bug in IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

window.onbeforeunload function not execute in IE correctly. Because some partial postbacks are also considered as "Trying to leave the page". 
If a link on the page has href="javascript:...." (ASP.Net LinkButton is rendered like this), IE will incorrectly fire the window unload event when the link is clicked.
so, I kept a dirtyflag variable and added

```
var __ignoreDirtyFlag = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $('[href^="javascript:"]').bind('click.ignoreDirtyFlag', function () {
            __ignoreDirtyFlag = true;
        });
    }
});
```

now when page is loaded, for links started with href^="javascript:" will assigned that function. when link is clicked then it make __ingoreDirtyFlag variable true;
then added

```
window.onbeforeunload = function globalWindowUnload() {
    if (!__ignoreDirtyFlag && isDataFilled == true) {
        return "You have unsaved changes on this page. If you leave this page, those changes will be lost.";
    }
    __ignoreDirtyFlag = false;
    return;
};
```

if there is any asp update panels you have used in your page, above function binding to the link will be removed.
so we have to bind function to the links again when update panel get refreshed.

so,

```
function foo() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
}

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    // Do your stuff
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $('[href^="javascript:"]').bind('click.ignoreDirtyFlag', function () {
            __ignoreDirtyFlag = true;
        });
    }
}
```

and

for body tag onload method, I assinged foo() method.
`<body onload="foo()">`

this hack is working fine with IE and all the browsers :)
thanks

Comment: This answer is technically interesting. Too bad it is so hard to read.

Comment: Didn't see the *jquery* tag

Comment: Hey, I know that this answer is almost 3 years old, but do you think you could add a non-jquery version of your answer since the question was not tagged as jquery?

Answer (score 0):

`var inFormOrLink = false;
var url_auth = '';
var __ignoreDirtyFlag = false;

```
document).ready(function () {

if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('').bind('click.ignoreDirtyFlag', function () { __ignoreDirtyFlag = true; alert("teste luiz") });

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (!__ignoreDirtyFlag) {
            return "Tem certeza que deseja encerrar a sessão TESTE LUIZ?";
        }
        __ignoreDirtyFlag = false;
        return;
    };
}
else {
    $('*').live('click', function () { inFormOrLink = true; alert("Passou aqui 1 LUIZ"); });
    $('*').bind('submit', function () { inFormOrLink = true; alert("Passou aqui 2"); });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (!inFormOrLink) {

            if (window.location.href.indexOf("DEV2") != -1) {
                $.post("/DEV2/SSQ/AUTH/LOGOUT", null);
                return 'Tem certeza que deseja encerrar a sessão TESTE DEV2?';
            }`
```

Comment: For most answers it is a good idea to add an explanation to show how the code works, this helps other people with less programming experience understand what the code does.

Comment: Purpose is to logout the user whenever he closes the browser or manually change the destination url.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose is to logout the user whenever he closes the browser or manually change the destination url

```
var url_auth = '';var __ignoreDirtyFlag = false;$(document).ready(function () {if ($.browser.msie) {$('a').live('click', function () { __ignoreDirtyFlag = true;}); $('*').bind('submit', function () { __ignoreDirtyFlag = true; });window.onbeforeunload = function () {if (!__ignoreDirtyFlag) {if (window.location.href.indexOf("DEV2") != -1) {$.post("/DEV2/SSQ/AUTH/LOGOUT", null);return 'Tem certeza que deseja encerrar a sessão ?';}}};
```